# "device.uuid" cordova not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

Added cordova device plugin using command,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

but still "`device.uuid`" not working.

Please refer the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova-7.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.getElementById('deviceProperties').value = device.uuid ;
    }

    </script>
<body class="screen_background">
<div class="scrollable screen_background">
  <div class="scrollable-content">      
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 event_form_div">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 left_right event_form">ARTCHITECS TRUST</div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 left_right sevent_form_subtitle">Enter details to see the latest event</div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12  font_align input_box_div" ng-app="MobileAngularUiExamples" ng-controller="bookController">
                 <form method="post" name="latest_event" id="latest_event" ng-submit="insertData()">  
                    <input class="input_box" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="bname" required/>
                    <input class="input_box" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="bemail" required/>
                    <input class="input_box" type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact" ng-model="bcontact" required/>
                    <input class="input_box" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" ng-model="baddress"/>
                    <input class="input_box" type="text" name="yearofpassing" placeholder="Year Of Passing" ng-model="byear"/>
                    <input class="input_box" type="hidden" name="duid" id="deviceProperties" ng-model="bduid">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default sub_btn" value="Submit"> 
                </form>
               <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default sub_btn" ng-click="insertData()">Submit</button>-->
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 left_right event_form_logo" ><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logoimg" class="logo"/></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What error do you get? make sure your cordova.js path is correct and if onDeviceReady function is getting fired.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I'm new to cordova. I am creating a build directly using command "cordova run android". After this I am installing this build to android phone. So can you please tell me how do I check error and how to find path for cordova.js.

Comment: Check your platform->android->assets->www. cordova.js file should be there. then you add file in index.html like
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks, I found js file. As you told I have also inserted into index.html. But still won't getting  device id. This time I have also tried running app in emulator and found this errors.

Comment: Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: C:\Users\mirackle\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

Comment: Above error has been solved. But still won't getting device id.